# Finding the smallest $x$ such that $ax\equiv b\mod m$

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking to solve for $x$ in the equation

$ax\equiv b\mod m$

and I wish to find the smallest $x$ which satisfies this. How would I go about doing this, in the general case? (This is for a programming problem).

What I've done so far is try to compute the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then multiply this inverse with $b$ which effectively does modular division $b/a$. But the problem is that sometimes $a$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse in the ring, while the equation can still be solved. For instance,

$2x\equiv 2\mod 6$

trivially has $x=1$ as the solution. But 2 has no multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. So I'm a bit stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2x\equiv 2\pmod{6}$  if and only if $1x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, where we divide by  $gcd(a,m)$ throughout.  There will then be $2$ solutions (the gcd) modulo $6$ (namely $1$ and $4$), but since you want the smallest (presumably ordered as positive integers) this isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks, $gcd$ of all three $a,b,m$ or something else?

Comment: If $\gcd(a,m)$ doesn't divide $b$, there are no solutions.  If it does, then what I wrote above applies.

Comment: Perfect! I got my program accepted by the automatic judge, after I added the $gcd$ division as you mentioned. Thanks a lot!